# Passing A Variable Number of Arguments into a Function

Tags: matlab, function, arguments

In Matlab, I have a variable length cell of values:

```
C={A1,...,An}
```

How should I pass and distribute these values into a function able to receive a variable number of arguments?

```
f(A1,...,An)
```

Ultimately if not possible, how should I modify the beginning of this function for making this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the cell array into a [comma-separated list](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) via curly-brace indexing, that is, use `C{:}`.

Example with the `reshape` function:

```
>> C = {ones(3,4), 2, 2, 3};
>> y = reshape(C{:});
>> size(y) % check
ans =
     2     2     3
```

Comment: I tried with `(:)`.... i was about to write a whole change for so tricky detail!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what 'varargin' does for you. Read in multiple variables, e.g. f(a,b,c), and store them in a cell-array.

Then you could go for one of these 'quick and dirty' processing methods:

```
function asdf(varargin)
  yourarguments=[varargin{:}]; % if all numerical
  yourargumentscontain=contains(varargin,'asdf'); %if strings contained
  all_processed_args=cellfun(@(x) whateveryouwant_function(x), varargin); %for older versions of matlab
end
```

For more here's documentation: https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/parse-function-inputs.html

Comment: This is the converse, for reading from a function, not for inputting into a function.

Comment: sorry, the answer assumes you're working with varargin. I guess this is not the case then.