# Performing operations on a variable number of workspace elements in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function

new MATLAB user here so apologies if this seems like a silly question. I have the following list of variables (doubles) in my workspace:

```
E1_01Strain  E1_06Strain  E1_07Strain  E1_08Strain  E1_09Strain  E1_10Strain  
E1_01Stress  E1_06Stress  E1_07Stress  E1_08Stress  E1_09Stress  E1_10Stress
```

These are lists of numbers. I would like to remove the last n elements from each variable. I can do it with the command

```
E1_01Strain = E1_01Strain(1:end-100)
```

but it's impractical because later I'm going to have to do it on many, many more similar variables. Therefore I wanted to write a function that accepts as inputs a list of the workspace variables (as in, I highlight the variables I want and drag and drop into the function input) and removes from each one n elements.

I understand that I can write a function like this:

```
function [X1, X2, X3, X4] = Remove_n_elements[n, X1, X2, X3, X4]
 X1 = X1(1:end-100);
 X2 = X2(1:end-100);
 X3 = X3(1:end-100);
 X4= X4(1:end-100);
end
```

but that would mean that I would have to change the number of inputs, outputs, and the lines of code in the function every time. I'm sure there's a better way to do it but I can't figure it out.

I keep thinking that there might be a way to do it by looping over all the inputs but I can't get it to work since (as far as I know) I need to create a list of the inputs and then the operation is performed only on the elements of that list, not the inputs themselves.

I was looking at [Passing A Variable Number of Arguments into a Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735705/passing-a-variable-number-of-arguments-into-a-function) and from that using inputParser from https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/parse-function-inputs.html but since I'm new to MATLAB I'm not sure how to use it for my case.

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html Then you can loop through the variables and do the code you suggest with each automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the code provided by il_raffa for a bit but followed his advice and went back and reconsidered how the script functions. After some more digging I wrote the following script that does exactly what I need. This script extracts the columns des_cols from all .csv files in a folder and plots them together. It then makes another plot of the averages.

```
files = dir('*.csv'); % navigate to the folder that you want to run the script on in MATLAB
avgStress = [];
avgStrain = [];
set(groot, 'DefaultLegendInterpreter', 'none') % the names of my .csv files have underscores that I want to see in the legend, if you don't want this then comment this line
hold on; %comment this and hold off further down if you want separate plots for every .csv
for file = files'
    csv = xlsread(file.name);
    [n,s,r] = xlsread(file.name);
    des_cols = {'Stress','Ext.1(Strain)'}; % type here the names of the columns you want to extract
    colhdrs = s(2,:);
    [~,ia] = intersect(colhdrs, des_cols);
    colnrs = flipud(ia);
    file.name = n(:, colnrs);
    file.name = file.name(1:end-600,:); % I wanted to remove the last 600 rows but if you want them all, remove the -600
    plot(file.name(:,2),file.name(:,1),'DisplayName',s{1,1});
    avgStress = [avgStress file.name(1:1500,1)]; % calculates the average stress for the first 1500 points, you can change it to whatever you want
    avgStrain = [avgStrain file.name(1:1500,2)];
end
ylabel({'Stress (MPa)'}); % y-axis label
xlabel({'Strain (%)'}); %x-axis label
title({'E_2'}); % title of the plot
legend('show');
hold off; % commment this if you want different plots for all .csv files
avgStress = mean(avgStress,2);
avgStrain = mean(avgStrain,2);
plot(avgStrain,avgStress);
```

This creates two plots, one with all the raw data and another with just the averages. I hope this helps anyone that might have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is to review the architecture of your SW in order to avoid the needs to perform such operations on the Workspace variables.

That is: how those variables are created? Are these variables loaded from a ".mat" file? etc.

Anyway, in order to avoid using the `eval` function and given your situation, a possible approach could be:

- identify the names of the varailbes by using the function `who`. You can specify in the call to `who` the root name of the varaibles and use the `*` as, for example, `who('E1*')`. Make sure it fit wiht the desired variables. You can also use `regexp` to better refine the selection of the variables
- save these varaibles in a temporary `.mat` file: the name (including the path of the temporary file can be created with the function `tempname`
- load the temporary `.mat` file: this will create a `struct` in the Workspace whose fields are the variables you want to midify
- call the function to remove the undesired elements form the fields of the struct. The function have to return the updated struct
- save the updated struct in the temporary file
- load again the temporary file by specifying the option `-struct` which allows loading the content of the file as single varaibles

The function to remove the undesired elements can be made as follows:

- get the nams of the struct's fields by using the function `fieldnames`
- loop over the filed of the struct by using the `dynamic field names` property
- remove the undesired elements form the fields
- return the updated struct

A possible implementatin could be:

**Code "before" the call to the function**

```
% Get the names of the variables
list_var=who('E1*')
% Define the name of a temporary ".mat" file
tmp_file=tempname
% Save the variables in the temporary ".mat" file
save(tmp_file,list_var{:});
% Load the variables in a struct
sel_vars=load(tmp_file);
% Call the function to remove the elements
out_str=Remove_n_elements(8,sel_vars)
```

**Function to remove the undesired elements**

```
function sel_vars=Remove_n_elements(n,sel_vars)
% Get the names of the fields of the struct
var_names=fieldnames(sel_vars)
% Loop over the fields and remove the undesired elements
for i=1:length(var_names)
   sel_vars.(var_names{i})=sel_vars.(var_names{i})(1:end-n)
end
```

**Code "after" the call to the function**

```
% Save the updated struct in the temporary ".mat" file
save(tmp_file,'-struct','out_str')
% Load the updated struct as separate variables
load(tmp_file)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it helps a lot!

I understand what you mean about this method not being the best and you're right, I load the variables from several .csv files. The problem is that from the .csv I'm interested in only two columns out of 6 and then I need to plot all of them. I know that it's not possible to plot tables so I load the data as column vectors and then change their names to the list you saw above. Then I need to eliminate some cells at the end of each column and finally plot them. Like I said I need to do this for a variable number of .csv files.